# Explicit open cover of $\mathbb{R}$ by disjoint countable unions of open intervals

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

It is well-known that every open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is a disjoint countable union of open intervals; is there an explicit construction of an open cover of the whole real line consisting of collections of countable disjoint open intervals?

Comment: I think trivially, the whole real line, $(-\infty, \infty)$ works for what you are requesting.

Comment: @N. Owad. Yes, that is what I thought first; but I think in the proof of the proposition that every open set in $\mathbb{R}$
 is a disjoint countable union of open intervals, intervals are assumed to be of finite length; thus I am more interested in the non trivial case.

Comment: By the way, if you carefully read the proof of the theorem "every open set in $\mathbb{R}$
 is a disjoint countable union of open intervals", you will find these disjoint intervals are unique, i.e. $(-\infty, +\infty)$ is also the unique decomposition of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Asigan. I see, thank you and I think that $(-\infty, \infty)$ might be the only option.

Comment: @HaoqingYu The interval does not need to be bounded. The construction is for $x\in O$ where $O$ is open, we define $I_x=(i,s)$, and $i=\inf\{a: (a,x)\subseteq O\}$, $s$ the sup counterpart. $i, s$ are allowed to be $+$ or $-\infty$. Then $O=\cup_{x\in O} I_x$ (which is countable union since for $x,y\in O$ $I_x$ can be equal to $I_y$ even if $x\ne y$). And this implies $I_x$ is uniquely determined since it is the "maximal" interval in $O$ contains $x$.

Comment: Yeah, the well known theorem isn't true if you only allow bounded open intervals.

Comment: $\Bbb R$ is a connected space. You cannot partition it into a finite or infinite family of 2 or more non-empty disjoint  open subsets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $]a,b[$ is an interval of the family covering $R$. The point $a$ is in $R$ but not in $]a,b[$. If $a$ were in another interval $]c,d[$, a nbrd of $a$ enclosed in $]c,d[$ should contain points of $]a,b[$, which is impossible. The family does't cover $R$.